# How to switch from one of Tab bar view to another view using xib

Tags: ios

Suppose I have 3 tabs on tab bar controller:

- `TabAViewController`
- `TabBViewController`
- `TabCViewController`

and in tab `C` I have one button.

When I click on that button then open the another View (`CsubViewController` which is not `TabAViewController`, `TabBViewController`, `TabCViewController`). How to call that Another View (`CsubViewController`) on button click?

And how to come back to the same view after back button click.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you are using a NavigationController as the root controller, you push the CSubViewController in your current ViewController by

```
navigationController.pushViewController(...)
```

and go back with

```
navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(...)
```

which is the simplest way to achieve your goal.

Or you can write your own code and try to present the CSubViewController modally in traditional presentViewController(...) and dismissViewController way.